# Console kernel dies when running 3D plot in ipython

Tags: python, arrays, plot, kernel, die

So I'm trying to run a 3-d plot with a structured array that consists of a huge shape and size.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os


path = '/users/username/Desktop/untitled folder/python files/MSII_phasespace/'

os.chdir( path )

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

data = np.load('msii_phasespace.npy',mmap_mode='r')


# data.size: 167197
# data.shape: (167197,)
# data.dtype: dtype([('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4'),
  # ('velx', '<f4'), ('vely', '<f4'), ('velz', '<f4'), ('m200', '<f4')])

u = data['x']
v = data['y']


X, Y = np.meshgrid(u, v)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, data[0:1])

plt.show()

data.close()
```

Unfortunately running the file leads to the kernel to continuously die. 
Even when i slice the array to one variable. Pretty weird right? I don't seem to know what the case is. My assumption is that it is either i have a improper placement of my close() command, there is a continuous loop of the data processing, or my computer is unable to support this type plot generation. Or maybe something else with my code?

Any help and/or guidance is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

also, the size, shape, type is listed in #.

Comment: When you say die, what exactly do you mean? Does it freeze? Is there an error message or a stack trace you could show us?

Comment: Hello again, Mad Physicist. Running the program leads to the memory usage status to climb up to 85-89% and then drops down to ~ 30%, showing the message `It seems the kernel died unexpectedly. Use 'Restart kernel' to continue using this console`

Comment: IPython, perhaps in Spyder?

Comment: Sorry. I'm running it on a ipython console in spyder.

Comment: Try from the command line outside of spyder.

Comment: Tried it on the Jupyter QtConsole. It still crashed.